# How to convert two columns into one column of CSV?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

This is how my columns currently look. There are two columns, each having a name. I want something as shown below in the expected section, for better processing of a parsing task.

**Current**

```
Col A       Col B
Name        Name 
Name        Name
```

**Expected**

```
Col A
Name,Name
Name,Name
```

Comment: What's the meaning the dots in the current situation? I'm a bit confused, the expected situation shows one column header and two columns below it, unless "," isn't your separator. Could you clarify this?

Comment: Dots are just nothing here, its just done to make it visible so you can understand it. Col A and Col B are two seperate columns.

Comment: This is really unclear.  If the dots are nothing, is your delimiter a space or a tab in `Current`? It looks like you are trying to just remove "Col B" between the two.

Comment: For those that appear to be unsure of what the user is asking for: It appears the user is trying to take two columns, one with header Col A and another with Col B and merge the two. So the data in Col B gets appended to Col A

Comment: No, you are not getting the problem. I have two columns, A and B. They both have names. They are standard columns and there is no such thing as a delimiter between them. I want them to be name,name in one column.

Comment: So you want the result to be one column with ROW1 A1,B1  ROW2 A2,B2  ROW3 A3,B3? With the data coming from the original A and B columns?

Comment: I dont know, you guys tell me, I am an Excel noob. It is already in a CSV format but it has columns.

Comment: I made an edit to your initial post so others can understand it. I also posted an answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, there is a delimiter.  It is how excel knows to treat the data as two columns.  "CSV" means "Comma Separated Value", but other delimiters can be used.  If the task is a programmatic parser, then you should look at the file in the raw format rather than excel (open it in `notepad.exe`, for example) to see what actually separates the data.  The default for a "CSV" is a comma.  If you are trying to use excel, then you should use the excel format, `xlsx` (2010+) which would keep formulas and let you store values delimited by anything in them. Your `name,name` by default would open with 2cols.

Comment: Try opening your CSV file in notepad. Does that show the data how you are expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open excel:

Let's create a Col C

So we have:

```
Col A         ColB        Col C
Joe           Bryan        (c1)
Alex          Danny        (c2)
```

In C1, type the following as a formula: `=A1&","&B1` and press enter

This will then merge Joe and Bryan to have a comma looking like so: `Joe,Bryan`

Then copy and paste the new data in C1 `as a value` into A1 (Col A where Joe is)

Comment: Will this come out like Joe,Bryan , Alex,Danny?

Comment: Please see my edit to have it come out like `Joe,Bryan` - aka just do `=A1&","&B1`

Comment: @falconspy I edited your answer to complete your edit (you forgot to edit the second-to-last line), but it's waiting for peer review..

Comment: You can also wrap the formula in `=trim()` if there are extra spaces in the cells.

Comment: I have to drag down 30k rows, any way it fills up automatically?